# Using XPMainifest to incorporate Google Maps in Delphi

Tags: xml, google-maps, delphi, windows-xp, manifest

I want to incorporate Google Maps in my Delphi program.

I Found this [link](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/).

I copied the code exactly, but my programs doesn't work. I realised that under uses there is XPMan.

```
uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, XPMan, ComCtrls,MSHTML;
```

I hadn't included the `XPManifest` at the time but the problem is I'm not sure how to use it. What do you have to do besides just dropping it on the form?

I read this:

> The manifest can be embedded inside the program file (as a resource)
>   or it can be located in a separate external XML file.

How exactly is this done and what must be written?

Is this the problem or would there be something else that is making my program not work? I'm also open to any suggestions on a better way to incorporate Google maps in my program.

Comment: You don't need XPMan if you're working in recent versions of Delphi. It's an old legacy component that does nothing but add a resource directive (`{$R WindowsXP.res}`) to your application, as you can see if you examine its source code. In recent versions of Delphi, it is replaced by simply checking "Enable runtime themes" in your project options - remove XPMan from the uses clause. A Windows manifest has nothing to do with incorporating Google Maps into your app; that's all in MSHTML and SHDocVw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPMan unit, and the `TXPManifest` component were added in Delphi 7. Their purpose is to link an XML application manifest to the executable. This manifest ensures that the application links to v6 of the comctl32 library which is needed to use XP themes.

This all has nothing whatsoever to do with Google Maps.

What to do next probably depends on which version of Delphi you have:

- If your Delphi does not recognise `XPMan` then it must pre-date Delphi 7. You should remove all references to `XPMan` and `TXPManifest`.
- If your Delphi is more modern and has the *Enable runtime themes* option then you should enable it and again remove all references to `XPMan` and `TXPManifest`.
- If you have an in between Delphi then you could use `XPMan` or not, as you please. If you want to do the simplest thing to do is to add `XPMan` to your .dpr file's uses clause. No need to bother with the component which does nothing more than ensure that you use the unit.